# Playn Sample - How can I use Android res Folder as resources directory?

Tags: playn

**Story in short:** I was trying to make playn-showcase-android fit to any screen size. And came across many problems like we cant use 9-patch images, and if we go for scaling, it blur, scale9 images doesn't stretch well when there is text on it..

Finally I decided to make my showcase-android res/ folder to be default resource folder, at least for the Android version. I have tried to edit playn source, but realized that it takes the resources path from class loader.

Is there any thoughts about this? How can I use res/drawable Images for atleast Android version? like in the android specific way.. so that I can make the UI better.

Answer (score 0):

`blur` in `PlayN` you can disable as follows:

```
graphics().ctx()
.setTextureFilter(GLContext.Filter.NEAREST, GLContext.Filter.NEAREST);
```