# layer.setScale() linear/nearest neightbour scaling?

Tags: scale, playn

I'm using low resolution graphics and am aiming for the retro pixelated look. However, layer.setScale() seems to smooth the graphics when scaling up. And the function doesn't take any parameters.

Anyway to change the way scaling is done?
I'm not completely sure what the right terms are, but I use either "linear" or "nearest-neighbour" scaling to achieve the effect in other frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

[Playn Sample - How can I use Android res Folder as resources directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11432674/playn-sample-how-can-i-use-android-res-folder-as-resources-directory)

according to that link, you can use something like

```
graphics().ctx().setTextureFilter(GLContext.Filter.NEAREST, GLContext.Filter.NEAREST);
```